# Sum and percentage on json array elements

Tags: json, postgresql

My table is like this:

```
create table alphabet_soup(
id numeric,
index json bigint
);
```

my data looks like this:

```
(id, json) looks like this: (1, '{('key':1,'value':"A"),('key':2,'value':"C"),('key':3,'value':"C")...(600,"B")}')
```

How do I sum across the json for number of A and number of B and do % of the occurence of A or B? I have about 6 different types of values (ABCDEF), but for simplicity I am just looking for a comparison of 3 values.

I am trying to find something to help me calculate the % of occurrence of a value from a key value pair in json. I am using postgres 9.4. I am new to both json and postgres, and I am landing on the same json functions manual page of postgres over and over.

I have managed to find a sum, but how to calculate the % in a nested select and display the key and values in increasing order of occurence like follows:

```
value    | occurence   |  %
====================================
A        |      300    |  50      
B        |      198    |  33    
C        |      102    |  17
```

The script I am using for the sum is :

```
 select id, index->'key'::key as key
    sum(case when (1,index::json->'1')::text = (1,index::json->'2')::text 
 then 1
    else 0
end)/count(id) as res
from
alphabet_soup
group by id;
limit 10;
```

I get an output as follows:

```
 column "alphabet_soup.id" must appear in the group by clause or be used in an aggregate function.
```

Thanks for the comment Patrick. Sorry I forgot to add I am using postgres 9.4

Comment: What is your PG version? Please also post table structure and the form of the json documents.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to do this is to expand the `json` document into a regular row set using the [`json_each_text()`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-json.html) function. Every single `json` document then becomes a set of rows and you can then apply aggregate function as you would on any other row set. However, you need to use the function as a [row source](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/queries-table-expressions.html#QUERIES-FROM) (section 7.2.1.4) (since it returns a set of rows) and then select the `value` field which has the category of interest. Note that the function uses a field of the table, through an implicit `LATERAL` join (section 7.2.1.5).

```
SELECT id, value
FROM alphabet_soup, json_each_text("index");
```

which yields something like:

```
test=# SELECT id, value FROM alphabet_soup, json_each_text("index");
 id | value
----+-------
  1 | A
  1 | C
  1 | C
  1 | B
```

To this you can apply regular aggregate functions over the appropriate [windows](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/tutorial-window.html) to get the result you are looking for:

```
SELECT DISTINCT id, value,
  count(value) OVER (PARTITION BY id, value) AS occurrence,
  count(value) OVER (PARTITION BY id, value) * 100.0 /
                            count(id) OVER (PARTITION BY id) AS percentage
FROM (
  SELECT id, value
  FROM alphabet_soup, json_each_text("index") ) sub
ORDER BY id, value;
```

Which gives a result like:

```
 id | value | occurrence |     percentage
----+-------+------------+---------------------
  1 | A     |          1 | 25.0000000000000000
  1 | B     |          1 | 25.0000000000000000
  1 | C     |          2 | 50.0000000000000000
```

This will work for any number of categories (ABCDEF) and any number of `id`s.

Comment: Hi Patrick, thanks for the reply. I am unclear what is the value that you have referred in your code. The script I have has two fields id and index json. the json is made up of key-value pairs. I am unclear if this is the value you are able to extract (without casting?)

Comment: The function `json_each_text()` produces a row source ("table") with two columns `key` and `value`. The `key` column is not of interest in your query, but the `value` column is. Casting is not necessary because the function produces `text` columns and these can simply be compared to do the summing.

Comment: Hi @wizengeeky. You edited my answer into another question but this was - correctly - rejected by the reviewers. Please post a new question with a link to this question (use the `share` link at the bottom left of my answer for a permalink) and I will gladly have a look at it.

Answer (score 0):

@ Patrick, it was an accident. I am new to stackoverflow. I did not realize how ti works. I was fiddling around and I found the answer to the question I asked in addition to the first one. Sorry about that!

For fun, I added some more to the code to make the % compare of the result set:

```
With q1 as 
(SELECT DISTINCT id, value, 
count(value) OVER (PARTITION BY id, value) AS occurrence, 
count(value) OVER (PARTITION BY id, value) * 100.0 / count(id) OVER(PARTITION BY id) AS percentage 
FROM ( SELECT id, value FROM alphabet_soup, json_each_text("index") ) sub     
ORDER BY id, value) Select distinct id, value, least(percentage) from q1   
Where (least(percentage))>20 Order by id, value; 


The output for this is: 
  id | value | least 
 ----+-------+--------
   1 |   B   |  33 
   1 | C     | 50
```